# Is there a GUI designer for C++/GTK?

Tags: c++, windows, ide, gtk

I'm .NET programmer and I'm looking for an IDE equivalent to VS  that I can drag and drop the controls etc to my form. MonoDevelop uses Gtk# library, but I can't do use of it (in this project) of languages interpreted or compiled to byte code. For this reason was C++ chosen.

Comment: What is the platform you're developing at?

Comment: What about [Crow Designer](http://code.google.com/p/nothing-personal/)?

Comment: First google hit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B#GUI_designers

Comment: @mike.dld: Windows. I added in tags

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There no windows version. :(

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:Sorry for don't mention before. it have to be Gtk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the standalone [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) tool for designing GTK+ based user interfaces. Also see the section on [Glade and Gtk::Builder](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/chapter-builder.html.en) in the gtkmm tutorial.

If you were on Linux, I could also recommend [Anjuta Devstudio](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/downloads.html) for an IDE, but I am afraid its Windows support is non-existent and there are even no binaries available for download.